# State_machine previous state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am using rails state_machine gem. I have one model Lead with a status field. Can I change the status to a previous status from where it is changed with using the state_machine?  I have a contact check box, when user will click it it will be lead.made_contact!  but when they are unchecked it should be reverted. Will state_machine help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're modeling interaction with a checkbox, it seems to me the only transition you can expect is to toggle it. Then, the status message can be a virtual attribute determined by the value of this state machine.

A state machine is probably overkill for this scenario, but assuming you're simplifying the problem for the sake of the question, here's another way to go about it.

```
class Lead
  state_machine :contact_state, :initial => :unchecked, :namespace => "contact" do
    event :toggle do
      transition :unchecked => :checked, :unless => lambda {|obj| obj.contact_state }
      transition :checked => :unchecked, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.contact_state }
    end

    state :checked, :value => true
    state :unchecked, :value => false
  end

  def status
    contact_state ? "lead.made_contact!" : ""
  end
end
```

That code produces the following behavior. You can, of course, change the namespacing or attribute to your liking.

```
irb(main):001:0> lead = Lead.new
=> #<Lead:0x007fccec42c898 @contact_state=false>
irb(main):002:0> lead.contact_state
=> false
irb(main):003:0> lead.status
=> ""
irb(main):004:0> lead.toggle_contact
=> true
irb(main):005:0> lead.contact_state
=> true
irb(main):006:0> lead.status
=> "lead.made_contact!"
irb(main):007:0> lead.toggle_contact
=> true
irb(main):008:0> lead.status
=> ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define steps explicitly like:

```
event :next do
  transition from: :without_contact, to: :with_contact
end

event :back do
  transition from: :with_contact, to: :without_contact
end
```

This way you can do `.next` and `.previous`

What makes the power of state machines is that you have to let the object handle itself.
You've to think hard about authorized and illicit transitions, then you just use events.

Having very explicit transition names is often the sign of a non abstracted state machine. (look at spree, the basically use one event: `next`, abstraction is total)

Comment: and another thing.. we can check wheather one event can be fires by lead.can_next? which will return boolean. There is a method in gem's source code. In event.rb there is a method can_fire?. can we use can_fire? to cehck wheather it event can be fires or not. What will be the syntax. I think lead.can_fire? will not work. Plz help.